# How to model a database to retain driver related information?

Tags: database-design

I am modelling a chauffeur-like system, where for each *driver* that registers in the platform, he/she can either be a "solo" *driver* or belong to an already associated *company*.

Independently of the type of *driver*, the following information is registered:

- *Driver ID* (Primary Key - I considered using this parameter in order to have the system more "ordered")
- *Name*
- *Email* (UNIQUE)
- *Phone Number* (UNIQUE)
- *Registration Date* (Time Stamp)

Now, if it's a "solo" *driver*, the following additional information will also be asked:

- *Vehicle type* (for example: 'car', 'motorbike', etc.)
- *Plate number* (UNIQUE)
- *Fiscal number* (UNIQUE)

If he/she belongs to an associated *company*, only the *name* of the *company* will be asked (since all the *vehicles* will be associated to the *car company*).

The *company* table will have the following attributes:

- *Company ID* (Primary Key - I considered using this parameter in order to have the system more "ordered")
- *Name*
- *Address*
- *Contact* (UNIQUE)
- *Email* (UNIQUE)
- *IBAN* (UNIQUE)
- *Fiscal Number* (UNIQUE)

Lastly, the *vehicle* table will have the following attributes:

- *Vehicle ID* (Primary Key - I considered using this parameter in order to have the system more "ordered")
- *Company ID* (Foreign Key)
- *Vehicle Type*
- *Plate Number* (UNIQUE)

A vehicle cannot exist as a standalone entity, i.e., it must be associated to a driver or to an existing company.

I would like to model this scenario using a relational DB since this info will be coupled with a routing algorithm. I'm having a difficult time finding a "clean" solution for this problem (specially considering that we are storing related-entity information, vehicle, in two different tables)... so, what's the best way to model this situation?

**Responses to clarification requests**

> 1. In your business domain, is it possible for a *solo driver* to eventually work for a *car company*?
> 2. Is it possible for a *driver* that works for a *car company* to become a *solo driver* only?
> 3. Can a *driver* be working for a *car company* and, at the same time, be working as well as a *solo dirver*?

Regarding questions 1 and 2, those are cases I haven't quite considered, but they seem plausible possibilities, so we can consider that those are possible scenarios.

Regarding question 3, for the moment, let's consider that a *person* can only be a *solo driver* or a *company driver*.

Comment: What you want is called "The Party Model". It uses table inheritance to allow you to point foreign keys at individuals or organizations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56199/discussion-between-g-farinha-and-mdccl).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a 'company' table as well that drivers can be associated to?

If so, one option is as follows:

Driver:

1. Driver_ID (PK)
2. Vehicle_ID (FK to Vehicle... nullable)
3. Company_ID (FK to Company... nullable)
4. solo_driver (boolean value [kind of optional, but could be useful])
5. other Attributes...

Vehicle:

1. Vehicle_ID (PK)
2. Company_ID (FK to Company... nullable)
3. Other Attributes...

Company:

1. Company_ID (PK)
2. Other Attributes...

If the driver is a solo-driver, then they have an associated Vehicle_ID
If the driver is a company-driver, then they have an associated Company_ID
- The company_ID would have associated (one-to-many) vehicle_ID's

Comment: That seems a great idea! In terms of good practice, is it possible that in allowing FK to have the NULL value it would have a negative impact on terms of system performance?

Comment: Moreover, in the Driver table, since a solo driver has more attributes than a driver that is associated with other company, what value would those attributes have when I'm registering a company driver? They are set to NULL?

Comment: FK having NULLs shouldn't have impact on performance. The key is to make sure you have good indexes built on the tables. Having NULL values is normal in many database systems. The values in the Driver table would be NULL.

Comment: what about creating another table whose attributes are the ones required for the individual driver and in the driver table we leave only the common attributes between the two types of driver? Do you think it would bring some benefits to the architecture of the system?

Comment: On first thought, I don't think there would be a huge benefit. You would end up (almost) always joining it anyways causing more action to occur in your execution plans... this would slow down query performance (possibly unnoticeable though.) Don't be afraid of NULL. :D

Answer (score 0):

The most common designs for this scenario are:

1. A single table with all columns, some of them will be NULL depending on type of chauffeur.
2. One table for each type of chauffeur.
3. A Main table for common data and additional tables for each type containing only unique columns specific for each type.

If number of chauffeurs is not really high, and since you have only 2 types of chauffeurs/specific column sets I would consider the first option, easier to maintain and no joins.

In Number 3 it might be easier to add new types if you need to, just adding one more table and not altering your previous ones.

Comment: I was trying to avoid a solution like that since it's fairly based on an (excessive) usage of NULL...don't you think there's a more "elegant" solution?

Comment: Yes, theres 3 to pick from, first one uses many nulls (as does previous answer, but on a single table).